# Move data from Postgres/MySQL to S3 using Airflow

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow

We are trying to move from Pentaho Kettle, to Apache AIrflow to do ETL and centralize all data processes under 1 tool.

We use Kettle to daily read data from Postgres/Mysql databases, and move the data to S3 -> Redshift.

What is the easiest way to do this? I do not see Operator that could directly do this; so Should i use MySQL/Postgres operator to put data in a local file, and the use S3 operator to move data to S3?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build your own operator 'mysql_to_s3' and add it as a plugin to Airflow.

There is an operator to archive data from Mysql to gcs:

[mysql_to_gcs.py](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py)

You can let all the code with a little change on `def _upload_to_gcs` using s3_hook instead: [s3_hook.py](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.py).

Documentation about custom plugins:

[Airflow plugins: Blog article](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2017/03/19/developing-workflows-with-apache-airflow/)

[Airflow plugins:  Official documentation](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/plugins.html)

Answer (score 2):

airflow-plugins (by Astronomer) has a `MySqlToS3Operator` that will take the resultset of a mysql query and place it on s3 as either csv or json.

The plugin can be found here:
https://github.com/airflow-plugins/mysql_plugin/blob/master/operators/mysql_to_s3_operator.py

From there you might be able to use the s3_to_redshift operator to load data from S3 into redshift: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/operators/s3_to_redshift_operator.html

Comment: Please note that the operator is a plugin coded and maintained by astronomer, and you have to import an astronomer hook

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás Thank you for noting. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás, how do you import an astronomer hook? I've searched their docs and haven't found anything. In other words, is it possible without purchasing a subscription?

Comment: It is indeed. Anyway, I am in the process of creating a MySQLToS3Operator: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6670 
If you need it right now and you don't want to wait until it is published you can copy the operator code to your airflow installation (it is totally functional)